# Ajuda com consulta em banco oracle

Tags: oracle

Como aumentar o salario em 0.1% dos que estão com salario inferior ao AVG de seu departamento

Essa é a tabela
[image: tabelaFuncionario]

Consegui tirar a média dos salários por departamento:

```
SELECT cod_departamento, AVG(VAL_SALARIO)
FROM FUNCIONARIO
GROUP BY COD_DEPARTAMENTO;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para aumentar o salário dos `FUNCIONÁRIOS` pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

1º - Vamos ver quais registros vão mudar:

[image: Repare nos 4 registros marcados]

De acordo com o departamento deles, 1, 2 e 3 é necessário ter respectivamente menos de ~3603, 2392 e ~1973 em `VAL_SALARIO` para que os seus salários aumentem em 10%.

[image: MÉDIA POR DEPARTAMENTO]

2º - Agora precisamos fazer o `UPDATE` nos registro, isso pode ser feito dessa forma:

```
UPDATE FUNCIONARIOS FUNC SET FUNC.VAL_SALARIO = FUNC.VAL_SALARIO * 1.10
WHERE FUNC.VAL_SALARIO < (SELECT AVG(FUNCIO.VAL_SALARIO)
FROM FUNCIONARIOS FUNCIO
WHERE FUNCIO.COD_DEPARTAMENTO = FUNC.COD_DEPARTAMENTO
GROUP BY FUNCIO.COD_DEPARTAMENTO);
```

Repare que o segredo aqui são os `ALIAS` que damos as `TABELAS` que são as mesmas, uma chamamos de `FUNC` e outra chamamos de `FUNCIO` para diferenciar uma da outra, dessa forma, o registro da tabela `FUNC` vai ser comparado na tabela `FUNCIO`.

Assim, atualizamos 4 registros.

[image: REGISTROS ATUALIZADOS]

Que são os 4 grifados anteriormente: `WILLIAN, VAGNER, ABNER e ANTONIO`.